# Bloquear un botón hasta que se seleccione una opcion

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<form name="formular" action="cualquiera.html" method="post"> 
<select name="transporte" type="check"onclick="document.formular.enviar.disabled=!document.formular.enviar.disabled" >  
  
<option >Coche</option> 
  
<option  >Avión</option> 
  
<option >Tren</option> 
  
</select> 
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" disabled> 
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He usado el evento `Onchange` en vez de `onClick` y la comprobacion de si el indice seleccionado es distinto al primero para que si no hay ninguno seleccionado, se bloquee de nuevo.

El cambio que hacias de la negación del estado anterior hacia que bloqueara y desbloqueara el boton intermitentemente sin ninguna lógica util.

```js
function activarBoton(){

var lista = document.getElementById("transporte");
var boton = document.getElementById("enviar");
if(lista.selectedIndex !=0 )
  boton.disabled = false;
else{
  boton.disabled = true;
}

}
```

```html
<form name="formular" action="cualquiera.html" method="post"> 
<select name="transporte" type="check" onchange="activarBoton()" id="transporte" >  
  
<option >Seleccione una opción</option>  
<option >Coche</option> 
  
<option  >Avión</option> 
  
<option >Tren</option> 
  
</select> 
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" id="enviar" disabled> 
  
</form>
```

Comment: pero lo que pasa es que tengo 2 onchange y me pone problema este

Comment: @KevinCastaño Puedes mostrar el codigo completo para que pueda adaptar mi respuesta?

Answer (score 2):

Siguiendo un poco tu estilo de desarrollo, aquí te muestro como deberías hacerlo:

```html
<form name="formular" action="cualquiera.html" method="post"> 
<select name="transporte" type="check" onclick="document.formular.enviar.disabled=this.selectedIndex==0" >  
  
<option >Coche</option> 
  
<option  >Avión</option> 
  
<option >Tren</option> 
  
</select> 
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" disabled> 
  
</form>
```

Sin embargo es importante mencionar que aunque puedes hacerlo no es buena practica colocar el código **javascript** dentro del **evento** `onClick` `onChange`, etc., lo correcto es crear una **función** con el codigo **javascript** y que esta sea invocada al ocurrir el evento, en el siguiente ejemplo te muestro una buena practica de como hacer:

```js
function enableSubmit(e){
 document.getElementsByName("enviar")[0].disabled=e.selectedIndex==0;
}
```

```html
<form name="formular" action="cualquiera.html" method="post"> 
 <select name="transporte" onChange="enableSubmit(this)" >  
  <option>Seleccione una opcion</option> 
  <option>Coche</option> 
  <option>Avión</option> 
  <option>Tren</option> 
 </select> 
 <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" disabled> 
</form>
```

Comment: me gusta tu respuesta (+1), también debí usar `selectedIndex==0` para ahorrar lineas de codigo ^^'  Un saludo